# Performance of views on redshift

Tags: powerbi, amazon-redshift

I have a cluster that I use, among other things, for reporting via PowerBi. For this I created views to show only the required fields so the queries run faster. If the source table is sorted by date and the view is 'select fields from table;' will it use the date if I query the view using WHERE on that field?
Any recommendations? For better performance!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better performance in Redshift, It is absolutely important to set SortKey, DistributionKey and Encoding properly. I guess you want to generate date wise report. In that case, the "date" column should be the distribution key. Do not encode the "date" column which means keep the value ENCODING as RAW / NONE. 
Then, you can use the "date" column as a COMPOUND sort key. If you have any other column you want to filter with then use that column as the first key and the "date" column as the second key in the SORT key order. Otherwise, you can define the SORT key only using the "date" column.